# script to move file and rename it with timestamp date

Tags: linux, windows, unix

I want to create script that use to move file and rename the file with timestamp. this is my script

```
mv D:\data\file\Daily_file.dat D:\data\file\Newfolder\Daily_file"%datetime%".dat
```

The file is moved but the file name like "Daily_%datetime%.csv" not with timestamp. I tried many ways like with `%date%` or without `"` but the result is not like I expected.

Comment: Why is this tagged linux and windows at the same time? The command uses a windows path. Also, please read the tag descriptions/wikis to see what the rules are for when they can or can't be used.

Answer (score 1):

**It works for me in linux**

```
$ mv <filename> <filename>_`date +"%d-%m-%Y"`
```

Comment: I'd suggest always to use $( date +"%d-%m-%Y" ) instead of backticks for substitution in bash.
Backticks can never be nested, but you can nest as many $( ) as you like ...

Comment: i tried this but the result is still daily_file`date+%m%d%Y`

Comment: Add snap of result

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the `date` bash function to get the current date into your path. Just replace `"%datetime%"` in your current move script with
`` `date +"%m%d%Y"` `` and it should work.